# Where is the command “conda” (Executable file in Anaconda ？

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda

I do not add `anaconda3/bin` into my `$PATH` variable  in ubuntu(run `which conda` return null).

I also can use `conda -V`  and  `conda -h`  in another directory.
Of course, the executable file `conda` in  `anaconda3/bin`  also works.
but another command like `jupyter` only works we are in the following directory `anaconda3/bin`.

I'm puzzled about it, the issue seems to be the environmental variable, I don't know how to fix it, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add the anaconda path to the bash

```
cd ~
gedit .bashrc    
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```